# Can a topic sentence occur at the second sentence of a body paragraph in an essay?

Tags: academic-writing

Can I bring up my topic sentence at the second sentence of one of the body paragraphs when I write an essay?

Comment: What do you mean by "bring up"?  Repeat it, or introduce it for the first time?  You say "one of the body paragraphs" so it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE, Reza! Could you illustrate your question with an example?

Comment: From one angle, easier communication has always been an issue among societies. The concern would be mitigated by more extinctions of languages.

Comment: From one angle, easier communication has always been an issue among societies. The concern would be mitigated by more extinctions of languages. As a result, people can be closer, more connected in many respects. Politically speaking, more understanding among nations and ethnics will be formed since misunderstanding is reduced. From economical aspects stronger ties will be built.

Comment: Hello, above is the whole paragraph. The second sentence is my top sentence of the paragraph. There are four paragraphs in my essay. This paragraph is the second one.